# Convergence of a similar-to-geometric series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

My goal is to find $C$, such that following function is a discrete weight function:

$p(j,k) := P[X=j,Y=k]=\begin{cases} C*(\frac{1}{2})^k &\mbox{for } k = 2, 3, ..., \ j=1,2,...,k-1 \\
0 & \mbox{else }\end{cases}\\$

Clearly, we need to find C, such that $\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}{\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}C * (\frac{1}{2})^k} = 1$

All I did was apply some simple calculus as can be seen here:

$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}{\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}C * (\frac{1}{2})^k} = C* \sum_{k=2}^{\infty}{(k-1) * (\frac{1}{2})^k} = C* \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{(k) * (\frac{1}{2})^{k+1}} = \frac{C}{2} * \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{k * (\frac{1}{2})^k}$

After that step, I am basically stuck. If it wasn't for the factor $k$ before, it would have been the geometric series and trivial to solve. I tried to come up with a sequence of partial sums and compute its limit, but I didn't see any pattern. Also, I don't know with which other sequences I could bound it from the top-/bottom to at least estimate the value of $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{k * (\frac{1}{2})^k}$.

The way I finally solved it was just to write out the first few summands, seeing that it seems to converge to $2$ and therefore chosing $C = 1$.

**Question:** Am I missing something? Is there a well known series I am apparently not aware of that helps me compute the series? If not, what is the *proper*, i.e. formal way of computing $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{k * (\frac{1}{2})^k}$ (maybe propose solution = 1 and then try to prove it...)?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: you have to do some Analysis
$$\sum_{k\ge 1}k\,x^k= x\sum_{k\ge 0}k\,x^{k-1}=x\Bigl(\sum_{k\ge 0}x^k)'=\dotsm$$